# super fast switch menu links without using tab

Tags: javascript, performance

http://www.revivalx.com/my/#home

try to navigate with the menu, the content load real fast, unlike a normal one. What is the technology behind? I'm sure it isn't tab because I inspected the markup and network tab with Chrome dev tool. Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of some of the files that have been included it's using [backbonejs.org](http://backbonejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The website is using Backbone.js

But the underlying technique being used is:

Its loading all the templates 
`http://www.revivalx.com/my/templates/content/privacyTemplate.html`
`http://www.revivalx.com/my/templates/content/aboutTemplate.html`
,etc

at page load and caching them. Then when you click on the menu it just replaces the html of the container with the template. So its sort of working like tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It is Simple jump to section trick.

First create div with id's like service contact etc.

```
<div id="contact" ></div>

<div id="service" ></div>
```

Make sure that the gap between them is such that they both doesn't appear on single page

Now create link like

```
<a href="#contact">contact</a>
<a href="#service">serice</a>
```